# How to add link to a collapsible item in a dropdown menu in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I need to be able to add a link to "Home" and "Pages" when clicking it but also to collapse and show the li items from below.

I changed "#homeSubmenu" from a href with a link but when clicking it does not collapse.

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>
    
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
               <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data-bs-target for the Collapse and href for the link..

```
      <li class="active">
                <a href="/" data-bs-toggle="collapse"  data-bs-target="#homeSubmenu" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
      </li>
```

Comment: I made the change but it doesn't work. If I remove the "data-bs-toggle="collapse" I can see all the content that I need when clicking on the pages. The issue is with the data-bs-toggle. When adding it it just collapses but not showing the page content. I need it to collapse but also to access the href link in the same time and show the content of that href link.